# Event.target.id returns an empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `event.target.id` property returns an empty string in my list item event click handler. Why is that?

```
$("ol").on("click", "li", function(event) {
 let id = event.target.id; // returns ""
});
```

I know I can get the `id` of the list item by using `$(this).attr("id")`, but I am just wondering why it is that the piece of code above returns an empty string for the `id`?

The event.target is most likely an `<li>` since I haven't gotten any other element in the DOM tree between the `<ol>` and the `<li>` and a bit of reflection says this:

[image]

Comment: Because event does not work like that. You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event to see what is available to you.

Comment: Try to `console.log` what's in `event.target` and let us know if you are expecting that element there. It would be helpful if you can show us what you have got in your HTML by making a [mcve].

Comment: Always console, That's the best solution to figure out the problem your self

Comment: It would be a **lot** clearer if you'd post an extract from the HTML. However note that in the console output the id is the empty string. Why do you expect the element to have an id value? They don't get one automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event target is not necessarily the `<li>` element.  Events bubble up the DOM tree.

Thus in:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <span>Hello World!</span>
</ol>
```

clicking on the text would trigger the event handler but the target would be the `<span>`, not the `<li>`.

You're using jQuery, so just refer to `this`. The library arranges for `this` to be a reference to the element relevant to the way the handler was set up.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ol").on("click", "li", function(event) {
    console.log("event target: ", event.target);
    console.log("this.id: ", this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li id="the-li-element">
    <span id="the-span-element">Hello World!</span>
</ol>
```

Note also that, ultimately, you'll only get a value for the id attribute of an element *if it actually has an id*.  The browser doesn't make up id attributes for everything in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am just not so great, JavaScript being duck-typed, in reflecting on what *type* the object I am looking at is.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 well the first thing to do is drop in `console.log(event.target)` and the browser will show you exactly what it is.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 answer updated. Everybody has one of those days :)  The question is still valuable even if your reason for asking it was simple confusion.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

In the below example, if you click on **abc**, the both the logs paint `2`, however, if you click on **def**, first logs paint `''` and second logs paint `2`.

```js
$("ol").on("click", "li", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
  console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ol>
    <li id="2">
      abc
      <span>def</span>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikhil. I do understand event bubble and capture phases and that there's a property named `currentTarget` and I've even used these properties both, in practice examples and in real world projects. I am perhaps forgetting why the li I get doesn't have an Id property set to the value of the property.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 well if the *actual* target of the "click" doesn't have an "id" value, why would you expect there to be a value? It's really not clear what exactly is confusing you here.

Comment: Personally I'd just use `this` because that's worked forever in jQuery.

Comment: It does have a value. The example is at https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/JavaScript/browser/cookies.html#L80

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 that in no way indicates that the element has an id. What does your actual **HTML** look like?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - In above example, click on `span` and inspect/log `event.target` and `event.currentTarget`. I think that will answer your question

Comment: @Pointy Damn, you're right. My bad. Sorry, I am doing too many windows at once. Thanks. Usually never me that clumsy. Will mark your answer in 3 mins.

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, again I am doing too many things all at once. I stopped to notice you never wrote an answer, and this answer, although factually correct, does not solve my problem because my problem was stupidity and carelessness. I really should not have posted a question until later.

Comment: Damn, you did post an answer. Please update your answer with the content of your comments and I will mark it as the right one.